# Forking and adding to FeatureLayer using ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, feature-layer, append

I am trying to find ways to join existing polygon feature layer with new data.  For example, Esri has a living atlas reference layer for US state boundaries: https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=99fd67933e754a1181cc755146be21ca

This layer also has some population data for each state.  I want to create a new polygon feature layer that is essentially a fork of this one.  I then want to add some data - in this case, voter turnout data for each state.  That data comes in excel format [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1h_2pR1pq8s_I5buZ5agXS9q1vLziECztN2uWeR6Czo0/edit#gid=2030096602) (source http://www.electproject.org). Once I have a copy of the states polygon feature layer with the new election data, I can create some nice visualizations.  I am trying to create a 2020 version of this feature layer: [US Voter Turnout 2016](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=b8a4e22b06f74c8882ef3294c46a49f6).  But I am having a hard time figuring out how to create and serve a layer from my own account that is a fork of that initial layer, and then add to it.

**I have tried** going into the Content section of arcgis online, hitting 'create', and creating a feature layer from an existing URL, using the arcgis server URL of the states boundaries item.  When I go through the form and hit 'Done', I get this error:

`Unable to add feature service definition. The operation failed because an index or statistics with name 'insights_fl_tauCNbQYU1nWzn8S' already exists on table 'user_72472.lklklkj_USA_STATES_GENERALIZED'.`

I have also tried going into the original boundaries layer, and exporting the data to an excel file.  Then I can add my new data as new columns.  Then when trying to create a new layer, I go to create a new Polygon FeatureLayer.  I hit 'Update Data', and then 'Append Data to Layer'.  I try to upload the excel file, but it gives the error: `No compatible layer was found in the uploaded file. Please check your file and try again.`

I feel like this should be relatively simple to do but I'm struggling to find a way, or any documentation on how to do this.

Comment: Hello @Seth Lutske, Do you have access to the desktop app, ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro maybe?

Comment: I do have access to Pro, but I don't have much experience with it.  But I'd be willing to dig in and make this a learning project if you know a way it can be done with Pro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Export and download the data as a shapefile
  [image]
- Add the shapefile in ArcGIS pro and use the Add join Tool to make a join based on States name, from the ArcGIS Online layer and the election table

[image]

[image]

- Once the join is successful share the layer as a web layer and use it in ArcGIS Online
  [image]

Comment: This worked great! There were a few extra steps I had to take, but it worked.  Follow up question:  Would an add-join work if the data being added is not 1 to1?  Meaning, if I had a new dataset with multiple rows for the same state (say different values for different dates for a time-aware layer), would the join still work?